# Chat refresh error with jquery

Tags: jquery

My  chat page works well except that the refresh sometimes loses the most recent comment. This seems to be a browser cache problem.

With form/POST, new comments are added to the LOG.txt file, which is then written to the display div. At two-second intervals the javascript refreshes the LOG.txt. This works well 95% of the time.

But sometimes a new comment appears and then vanishes, apparently from the javascript refreshing from the previous (cached?) version.

Relaunching the browser (clearing cache) usually fixes the problem. Leaving the window idle for a while (10 minutes?) usually causes it to start happening.

Is there a way to avoid this refresh error? Thank you for help.

AUTO-REFRESH

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doRefresh(){
        $("#show").load("LOG.txt");
    }
    $(function() {
        setInterval(doRefresh, 2000);
    });
</script>
</head>
```

ADD NEW COMMENT

```
<body>
<form id="box" method="post" onKeyPress="return checkSubmit(event)">
    <input name="new" autofocus="autofocus" type="text" >
</form>
<div id ="show"><?php include 'LOG.txt'; ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Solution: learn how to use signalr. Good luck.

Comment: Adding date stamp query to the LOG.txt call solves the problem. Use this – 

`code`function doRefresh(){
     $("#show").load("LOG.txt", "f" + (new Date()).valueOf() );
    }`code`

replacing this – 

`code`function doRefresh(){
     $("#show").load("LOG.txt");
    }`code`

Answer (score 1):

If cached content is the problem, disable jQuery's cache:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});
```

That txt is gonna be hughe some day.